# javascript: Serialize/deserialize class instance when posting to api

Tags: javascript, node.js

Basically, I want to be able to POST a serialized class instance (JS front end) to an endpoint and deserialize it on the other end (nodejs backend).
Since I'm using JS on both sides it seems like I should be able to use the same class def to do the serialization/deserialization and end up with an instance of the same class on the backend.

In this way, if the class def changes, the front and back end will be in sync.

Please can someone help with some approaches/libraries that might be good for the job - or if the above sounds totally mad then please tell me!

Comment: Add a `toJSON()` method in your class and send result to either end

Comment: I want the receiver to know what type of object to instantiate though - I could switch on a type param, but is there a better way?

Comment: What do you mean by "what type"?

Comment: If I pass an instance of class Dog, I want to instantiate a Dog on the receiver - but may not know what type to instantiate at runtime

Comment: So send an object like `{className:'Dog', data:{...}}`

Comment: yeah i guess that makes sense, thanks

Comment: And if you need the name do `somObj.constructor.name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made an npm module named [esserializer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esserializer) to solve this problem: save JavaScript class instance values during serialization, in plain JSON format, together with its class name information. The serialized text can then be POSTed to an endpoint:

```
// Browser side
const ESSerializer = require('esserializer');
const serializedText = ESSerializer.serialize(anInstanceOfClassX);
// Send Ajax POST request, with serializedText as data
```

Later on, during the deserialization stage in Nodejs server, esserializer can recursively deserialize object instance, with all types/functions information retained, using the same class definition:

```
// Node.js side
const deserializedObj = ESSerializer.deserialize(serializedText, [ClassX]);
// deserializedObj is a perfect copy of anInstanceOfClassX
```

If the class definition changes, the frontend and backend will be in sync, automatically.

Comment: Great work! I haven't tested it but this is really what I wanted to do, so have changed the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. Please let me know if you find any questions/problems on using this library.

Answer (score 0):

When an object has a `toJSON()` method you can define what needs to be serialized by `JSON.stringify()`

Then it's just a matter of setting up the constructor and `toJSON()` method to be compatible regarding input/output and you can send that json back and forth

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(state) {
    const defState = {foo: 'bar'}
    this.state = state ? Object.assign(defState, state) : defState;
  }
  
  get person(){
    return this.state.person
  }

  toJSON() {
    return this.state
  }
}

// local instance
const localInstance = new Foo({person:'Bob'});
const localJSON = JSON.stringify(localInstance);
console.log('Local class name : ',localInstance.constructor.name) 
console.log('LocalJSON', localJSON)


// remote instance from local JSON
const remoteInstance = new Foo(JSON.parse(localJSON))
console.log('Remote instance person : ', remoteInstance.person)
```